# Proving a ideal of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[image]

I am having trouble proving a.
My attempt:
I first have to prove that $0 \in \phi^{-1}(J')$. So $J'$ is an ideal, per definition $0 \in J'$. So take $x \in R$ such that $\phi(x)=0$ in $J'$. So $0 \in \phi^{-1}(J')$.

Now I have to prove $a-b \in \phi^{-1} \forall a,b \in \phi^{-1}(J')$. So per definition $a,b \in R$ and $\phi(a), \phi(b) \in J'$. I have to prove $\phi(a-b) \in J'$. I don't know how I would prove this, is it acceptible to use the definition of a ring homomorphism when the assignment doesnt mention one. So I would say $\phi(a-b) = \phi(a)-\phi(b)$, and $\phi(a)-\phi(b) \in \phi^{-1}(J')$.

Now I have to prove $\forall r \in R$ and $a \in \phi^{-1}(J'), ra, ar \in \phi^{-1}(J')$. This one I do not know how to start.

Comment: Do you understand the definition of the quotient map, and what they mean by "natural image"?

Comment: Also your first proof does not make sense - you say "take $x\in R$ such that $\phi(x)=0$".  First off, how do you know there even is such an $x$, and more to the point, how does that show $0\in \phi^{-1}(J')$?  Bottom line is you will need to use the definition of the quotient map.  Might be a good idea to review that section of your text before continuing.

Comment: I dont understand it that well but the quotient map maps an element $x \in R$ to the coset $xI$. And do they mean by natural image that it is a homomorphic image?

Comment: No, the quotient map maps an element $x$ to $x + I$.  You need to use that to answer these questions, e.g., for the first one, show that $\phi(0)\in J'$.  You'll need to use the fact that the "$0$" element of the quotient ring is $0+I=I$.  As for whether it's a homomorphic image, it is.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So i understand that $\phi(0) = 0 + I = I$. So I have to show that $\phi(0) = I \in J'$. I just don't understand how I can show that an ideal I is a element of another ideal J'?

Comment: The elements of the quotient ring $R/I$ are cosets of $I$.  That means the elements of any ideal in $R/I$ are also cosets of $I$.

Comment: Okay thank you very much I understand proving the first part that $\phi(0) \in J'$. For proving $\phi(a-b) \in J'$. I can use a theorem stating: Let R be a ring and I a ideal of R. Then the natural image $\phi: R \rightarrow R/I$ is a surjective ringhomomorphism. So I can use the definition of ringhomomorphisms, take $a,b \in \phi^{-1}(J')$, per definition $\phi(a), \phi(b) \in J'$ and $\phi(a)-\phi(b) \in J' = \phi(a-b)$. So $a-b \in \phi^{-1}(J')$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that to show part a), you do not need to know how ideals in $R/I$ do look like exactly. Just knowing that $J'$ is an ideal is enough to prove that $\phi^{-1}(J')$ is an ideal in $R$. You also do not need to know that $\phi$ is a ringhomomorphism. I will show the statement straight from the definition of the quotient map $\phi$ into $R/I$ and by using general properties of ideals.

In order to show that $\phi^{-1}(J')$ is an ideal in $R$, we have to show 2 things:

$\textbf{1)} (\phi^{-1}(J'), +) $ is an additive subgroup of $(R, +)$

$\textbf{2)}$ For $a \in \phi^{-1}(J')$, $r \in R$, we have $ar \in \phi^{-1}(J')$ and $ra \in \phi^{-1}(J')$.

Proving $\textbf{1)}$: Let $a$, $b \in \phi^{-1}(J')$. We then have to show that $a-b \in \phi^{-1}(J')$, i.e. that $\phi(a-b) \in J'$, where $\phi(a-b) = (a-b) + I$. By definition of the addition in $R/I$ however, we have that $(a-b) + I = (a + I) - (b + I) = \phi(a) - \phi(b)$. Since $\phi(a)$, $\phi(b) \in J'$, it follows simply from the fact that $J'$ is an ideal in $R/I$, that the difference $\phi(a) - \phi(b) \in J'$ as well, since ideals are additive subgroups.

We still have to show that $0 \in \phi^{-1}(J')$. But $\phi(0) = 0 + I = I$. Since $I$ is the additive identity element (i.e. 0-element) in $R/I$ and $J'$ is an ideal in $R/I$, we have $\phi(0) = I \in J'$.

Proving $\textbf{2)}$: Let $a \in \phi^{-1}(J')$, $r \in R$. We show that $ra \in \phi^{-1}(J')$, i.e. that $\phi(ra) \in J'$. But $\phi(ra) = (ra) + I$ and by definition of multiplication in $R/I$, we have that $(ra) + I = (r + I) \cdot (a + I)$. Since $r + I \in R/I$ and $a + I = \phi(a) \in J'$ and $J'$ is an ideal in $R/I$, it follows that the product $(r + I) \cdot (a + I) \in J'$ as well. The exact same argument can be used to show that $ar \in \phi^{-1}(J')$ as well.

This completes the proof of statement a).

Note: The above arguments work for any ringhomomorphism and are even easier to show. Hence, the statement can be generalized, saying that pre-images of ideals are yet again ideals under ringhomomorphisms. More precisely:

Let $\phi: R \to S$ be a ringhomomorphism, and $J \subset S$ be an ideal in $S$. Then $\phi^{-1}(J) \subset R$ is an ideal in $R$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much!